# Can't launch hierarchy viewer from android adb shell

Tags: android, hierarchy

I'm trying to use hierarchy viewer and pixel perfect, following the demo found here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAgE7saQUUY&feature=related

and the information from the android developer site:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html

The two resources have hierarchy viewer in the /tools directory, but I don't seem to have it there. Any ideas for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is not installed on the devices... it is on your development machine in the Android SDK install tools folder.